# Using-declaration with multiple inheritance compiles with msvc but not with clang and gcc

Tags: c++

```
struct A { int i; };
struct B: A {};
struct C: A {};
struct D: B, C {
    using B::i;
    void f() {
        i = 0;
    }
};
```

It seems like I specified to use i from A from B, but compiler says

> error: 'A' is an ambiguous base of 'D'

To be honest, I don't really understand what `using B::i` does. As far as I know, it brings `i` from namespace `B`, to namespace `D`. But does namespace `B` contain `i` because it inherits `i` from `A`, or is it only namespace `A` that contains `i`? If latter, why

```
//A, B, C is same with above
struct D: B, C {
    void f() {
        B::i = 0;
    }
};
```

this just compiles with no problem?
As you can see, I'm confusing with whole concept of namespaces in terms of class inheritance. Can anyone explain how rules of namespaces, inheritance, etc. works with these examples?

Comment: A, B, C, D are not namespaces.

Comment: well I said so because I found the phrase 'classes are namespaces' in TC++PL, but I'm not sure I really understand that. Can you explain?

Comment: Classes are data types, they have [class] scopes. Namespaces are scopes.

Comment: Usually, when you are running into these kinds of issues, they are caused by a fundamental design flaw. The solution you are trying to achieve might not be the best. Do all classes need to inherit from each other? Is there a "has a" relationship, instead of an "is a". Inheritance isn't so popular for the past 10-20 years or so.

Answer (score 1):

`using B::i` is not useful there because there is no `i` in `B`. It is useful for function resolutions. `i = 0;` is `this->i = 0;`. Due to the multiple inheritance `this->i = 0;` is either `static_cast<B*>(this)->i = 0;` or `static_cast<C*>(this)->i = 0;`, that causes ambiguity.

In other words, `using B::i` brings the name `i` to the immediate scope of the class `D` and does not resolve the ambiguity.

The example of the useful `using`:

```
struct A { void f(); };
struct D: A {
    void f(int) { f(); }  // error: no matching function for call to 'D::f()'
};
```

```
struct A { void f(); };
struct D: A {
    using A::f;
    void f(int) { f(); }  // ok
};
```

Comment: But why "bringing the name `i` to the immediate scope of the class `D`" don't hide `static_cast<C*>(this)->i`? I posted a new question because it is too long to elaborate this question in comment. Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71047145/why-does-using-declaration-in-class-definition-sometimes-hides-names-from-its-ba).

Answer (score -2):

Keyword `using` got multiple meanings depending on context. And C++ class scope is a namespace in terms of name resolution, but is not exactly like a namespace - a statement which deserves attention. Using declaration in class scope is related to inheritance and inheritance isn't a namespace feature. On other hand, class scope cannot be expanded by later declarations while a namespace can be.

A `using` statement in a namespace scope can be a *using-directive* if used on a namespace, a *using-declaration* for namespace members and type alias and alias template declaration. In C++20 it can be used for enums.

A `using` in a class scope is a *using-declaration* and it refers to a name of base class member into derived class definition. This may allow to chance access mode, such as to expose a protected member of base class as a public member of derived. If the derived class already contains a member with the same name, parameter list and qualifications, the derived class member hides or overrides one that is introduced from the base class.

If the *using-declaration* refers to a constructor of a direct base of the class being defined (e.g. using `C::C`), all constructors of that base  are made visible.

Obviously for that the name it refers should be unambiguous, which isn't the case in your example. Class D contains class A twice, once as a base of class B and once as a base of class C. Fully qualified names for those will be `B::A::i` and `C::A::i`, shorthanded to `B::i` and `C::i`. Now there is a question: which of those your statement must be hiding and which one exposing as per what was said above? The `C::A::i` is a different name, so `B::i` is *allowed* to conflict with it. In addition to that, with all your access being default to `public`, any using-declaration in class-scope is superfluous.

If `using` is in a code block scope, it got same meaning as namespace using-declaration.

```
void f() {
    B::i = 0;
}
```

would be same as

```
void f() {
    using B::i;
    i = 0;
}
```

provided `B` *is a namespace*. `B` isn't a namespace and the second case would be ill-formed. QED, class scope isn't exactly a namespace.

*TLDR: Declaration `using B::i;` in a code-block scope will never refer to class member `B::i` in a standard-compliant compiler as the only usages are defined above. Readers keep insisting I wrote that it can.*

Comment: Using declaration `using B::i;` in a code block scope cannot refer to class member `B::i`.

Comment: @273K, it cannot, all I wrote that _same_ as namespace using-declaration. In conflicts because B::A is not a namespace.

Comment: I read your answer, but I still don't understand fully and got another question which is too long to write in comment. I posted new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71047145/why-does-using-declaration-in-class-definition-sometimes-hides-names-from-its-ba). Please help.

Comment: @273K do people somehow read whay diidn't write. I explicitly wrote `using B::i;` in a code block is namespace using, pubit people keep comment as it I wrote opposite.