# why does using-declaration in class definition sometimes hides names from its base class and sometimes not?

Tags: c++

```
struct A { int i; };
struct B { int i; };
struct C: A, B {
    using A::i;
    void f() {
        i = 0;
    }
};
```

This compiles happily. As far as I know, it is because `using A::i;` hides `B::i`.

```
struct A { int i; };
struct B: A {};
struct C: A {};
struct D: B, C {
    using B::i;
    void f() {
        i = 0;
    }
};
```

But this does not compile, saying `error: 'A' is an ambiguous base of 'D'`. I don't understand what's the difference between those two. Why `using B::i;` does not hide `C::i` here?

Edit: I'm not trying to make something with that design. I know I should use virtual inheritance most of the case. I'm just wondering about the syntax of c++.

Edit: I'm still confusing with answers (which is now deleted) such as "`B::i` is same as `A::i` in second example". What I'm wondering is why is that. Where can I find basic syntax rules that makes `B::i` and `A::i` same? I have "The C++ Programming Language" of Bjarne Stroustroup, but that book is simply unreadable to me as a non native English user. If you also have the book, I'd appreciate it if you tell me the section of the book describing this problem.

Comment: `A` is implemented at `B` and `C` independently, unless you make `A` a `virtual` base class, hence the ambiguity.

Comment: There's no B::i. There's B::A::i and C::A::i. Diamond inheritance is **bad**, don't do this.

Comment: If there's no B::i at all, why it does not make any compile error when I erase `i = 0` in second code? It seems like its not `using B::i` which causes error, but `i = 0`.

Comment: @kjh6b6a68 Yes, that's right. The name "i" is not looked up until you use it for something. (And `using` doesn't.)

Answer (score 0):

You formed the "Diamond of Death", well-known problem in C++, which is a design error novice programmer produces. Consider change the design. or, If you really wish it to be compiled, try this:

```
struct A { int i; };
struct B: virtual A {};
struct C: virtual A {};
struct D: B, C {
    using B::i;
    void f() {
        i = 0;
    }
};
```

Some more detail:
In your code, B has its own A inside its instance, and C has its own A inside its instance. By inheriting from both B, C, D has B::A, and C::A inside it. when you trying to assign a value in i, it may be a B::A::i or C::A::i. Therefore ambiguity arises, and compiler complains. My suggestion code is utilizing virtual inheritance, so, in this diamond, A is appearing in D only once, and the ambiguity is resolved.

Addition: If you wish not to use the `virtual` inheritance, specify what `i` you are assigning to. ex)`B::A::i = 0;`

Comment: I'm just wondering about the syntax of c++, not trying to do something with that design

Comment: @kjh6b6a68 If you wish to have really authorative reference, refer to ISO C++20 document. Although it is not a good source for learning, it defines the syntax.

Comment: `B::A::i = 0` still causes same compile error, but `B::i = 0` compiles well.

Comment: @kjh6b6a68 `B::A::i` is not legal in this case because `B` and `C` do not contain A in case of virtual inheritance.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie What I meant was it causes compile error in case of NOT virtual inheritance, because what K.R.Park wrote on the last line was that I can use `B::A::i` if I wish not to use virtual inheritance

Comment: @kjh6b6a68 in that case it's not legal either, because there is no `B::A::i` and `C::A::i` to result in a **gvalue**, there are `B::i`, and `C::i`. Again, classes are almost like namespaces, but they are not *exactly* like namespaces, "namespace" of class includes its  base members. WHen you do assignment, you require a **gvalue** classed as **lvalue** on left side of assignment